# Regex: add title="" to <img> tags but not if <img> between <script>-tags

Tags: javascript, php, regex

The regex `/<img[^>]+/` from a SEO plugin is causing my [mapping plugin](http://mapsmarker.com) to break, as it adds unescaped slashes to my JavaScript output.

I would like to suggest a fix for this, where `<img>`-tags are only enhanced with `title=""` if they are not within a `<script>` or `<script*...>`-tag.

To clarify:

- only on code like `blabla <img src="">blab` the attribute `title=""` should be added
- `<script>blabla <img src=""> blabla</script>` should stay as it is
- `<script type="text/javascript">blabla <img src=""> blabla</script>` should also stay as it is

Can anyone help with a regex for that? I found something with `(?! Expression)` for defining exclusions but am not quite sure how to use this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex for problems like this.  Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.  It's then trivial to only add the attribute to the proper nodes, and you can be 100% sure that similar problems won't crop up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know a regexp for it, but i know a way to work around it

```
function add_titles_no_scripts($page)
{
    /* split up page at each start of an script */
    $parts = explode("<script", str_ireplace("<script", "<script", $page));

    /* remove the first part from the list, as its before first script */
    $first_part = array_shift();

    /* add titles to first parts as usal */
    $new_page = add_title($first_part);

    /* for all other parts */
    foreach($parts as $current_part)
    {
        /* split up part in 2 parts, before and after end of script */
        $sub_parts = explode("</script", str_ireplace("</script", "</script", $current_part), 2);

        /* make sure we have 2 parts */
        if(count($sub_parts) == 2)
        {
            /* add first part as it was inside the scripttags removed by explode */
            $new_page .= "<script" . $sub_parts[0] . "</script";

            /* adds 2nd part as usal */
            $new_page .= add_title($sub_parts[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            /* if only one part, we are inside an not ended script tag */
            $new_page .= "<script" . $sub_parts[0];
        }
    }

    /* return the new page */
    return $new_page;
}
```

Comment: thanks - I sent this to the developer @prelovac - hope it helps (although I fear he would prefer a new regex, as this is the code that is causing the trouble:

 `function seo_friendly_images($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/<img[^>]+/', 'seo_friendly_images_process', $content);
}`

Comment: Regex aren't the way to go... there is always a programmtic way to do it.

Comment: I know, the problem is that the solution should be as easy as possible as the other plugin author has to implement it in his plugin - so regex would fit better here I guess